# Atom & eslint: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-react-app'

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, create-react-app, eslint

Since I reinstalled my NPM dependencies in my create-react-app project, Atom's eslint gives me this error on the top of every file :

```
Error while running ESLint: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-react-app'.
```

While `react-scripts`'s eslint doesn't raise any warning or error. By the way, the package `eslint-config-react-app` **is** installed in `node_modules`.
I tried to reinstall linter-eslint, atom, the NPM dependencies, etc. Nothing worked.

Has anyone an idea ?

Here is my .eslintrc :

```
{
  "extends": "react-app",
  "rules": {
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-comment-textnodes": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": ["warn", {
      args: "all",
      ignoreRestSiblings: false,
      argsIgnorePattern: "^_$"
    }]
  }
}
```

Edit : I don't know why, but all of the sudden, the error changed and now it's this one on top of every js file :

```
Error while running ESLint: Invalid regular expression flags
```

**EDIT 2**

None of the given solutions worked in my case. The problem with `linter-eslint` is not solved. But I found a workaround for now : using `fast-eslint` instead of `linter-eslint`. Works just fine.

Comment: npm i -g babel-eslint@^7.2.3 eslint@^4.1.1 eslint-plugin-flowtype@^2.34.1 eslint-plugin-import@^2.6.0 eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^5.1.1 eslint-plugin-react@^7.1.0

Comment: In my case using vscode, this happened when I imported multiple projects. So I closed everything and imported only my project as a root folder

Comment: Are you installing ESLint globally or locally? Atom might be using the globally installed one and can not resolve locally installed plugins.

Comment: @Jdub This doesn't work.

Comment: @YoannesGeissler Not my case, I'm using Atom and other eslint configs in other open projects are working just fine.

Comment: @Jackyef I have eslint both globally and locally.

Comment: Can you check whether atom is using the global one or local one? Maybe this can help: https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint

Comment: @Jackyef It was using the local one. I changed it to global, restarted Atom, still the same error.

Comment: Have you by any chance try running `npm audit fix`, this sometimes fix all the dependencies errors.

Comment: @Strebler which version of react-scripts are you using?

Comment: Do you have the same problem when creating a new react app?

Comment: What does your eslintrc.json look like?

Comment: @mancristiana I'm using the latest version (3.2.0) but when creating a new CRA project, I don't have the issue... o_O

Comment: @RuudVerhoef I edited the post to include the .eslintrc

Comment: @Strebler could you remove the no-unused-vars rule and see if the error persists? So remove "no-unused-vars": ["warn", {
      args: "all",
      ignoreRestSiblings: false,
      argsIgnorePattern: "^_$"
    }]

Comment: @RuudVerhoef Done but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying this, one solution is installing eslint-config-react-app globally, along with all of its peer deps. At the moment, that's:

Refer to https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3633#issuecomment-361485857

```
npm i -g babel-eslint@^7.2.3 eslint@^4.1.1 eslint-plugin-flowtype@^2.34.1 eslint-plugin-import@^2.6.0 eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^5.1.1 eslint-plugin-react@^7.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that the problem occurred after you reinstalled
npm modules, it might be related to npm dependency resolution. So
you might have multiple versions of the same module and atom might
use the wrong one.

1. Check whether your react-scripts version is 0.2.0 or higher according to [Displaying Lint Output in the Editor](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#displaying-lint-output-in-the-editor)
2. Remove all `eslint` related dependencies from your `package.json`.

   This means removing `babel-eslint`, `eslint`, `eslint-plugin-flowtype`, 
   `eslint-plugin-import`, `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`, `eslint-plugin-react`, etc

   Create react app installs all the linting dependencies  under the
   hood so you shouldn't manually install them.
3. Remove all **global** `eslint` related dependencies.

   Generally you don't need to use globally installed eslint dependencies as you might 
   have different eslint versions in each of your projects.

The latest version of [linter-eslint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint) should then use the correct eslint dependencies from under `node_modules` in your project.

**UPDATE**: Based on your comments and edited question, I tried reproducing this using CRA, replacing the dependencies in `package.json`, reinstalling and adding the following `.eslintrc`.

Notice I added `"` around the options keys in the `"no-unused-vars"`.

```
{
  "extends": "react-app",
  "rules": {
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-comment-textnodes": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": ["warn", {
      "args": "all",
      "ignoreRestSiblings": false,
      "argsIgnorePattern": "^_$"
    }]
  }
}
```

Having done all this I couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have no such dependencies in my package.json (here it is : https://pastebin.com/jJ5YL1NN). As someone made me realize in the comments, starting a fresh CRA installation doesn't give me any error, weird (which also means there is nothing wrong with global dependencies).

Comment: About your update : linter-eslint doesn't give you an error in Atom ? What's your config of linter-eslint ? There is something wrong with my project though. When I git clone it on another linux with another Atom & everything installation, I still have the same error.

Comment: I used the default settings for linter-eslint, except I enabled automatic fixes (e.g fixing errors on save). 
Make sure your Global ESLint is disabled (this is by default).